# Fullcalendar resource view display a full day and make it scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, view, fullcalendar

I've found a nice implementation of a resource view for the jquery plugin fullcalendar.
[Fullcalendar Resourceview by Jarno Kurlin](http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/)

However for the resource day-view I can't get a full day to display and I would like to make this view scrollable like in the Agenda View which comes with the original fullcalendar.
Did anyone attempt this? What would be the best way to implement the scrolling?
Thanks in advance for any help on this matter.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to apply simple css to add scrollbars.
An inspection of the DOM reveals that there is a div holding the resource view similar to this:

```
<div class="fc-view fc-view-resourceDay fc-grid" style="position: relative; display: block;" ...
```

The `fc-view` class has the css property `overflow` set to `hidden`. You can override this in your own css file to be `scroll`

eg.

```
.fc-view {
    overflow : scroll
}
```

If you want to only set it for the *resource day* view, then just do this:

```
.fc-view.fc-view-resourceDay {
    overflow : scroll
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use overflow because when rendering it calculates position absolut and when you change days with scroll in the middle it displays the events wrongly

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this myself, I have a lot of resources and it makes each column too small so I added this to make the columns wider:

```
.fc-day-content {width:150px!important;}
```

and then used this for the scroll bars:

> .fc-view {overflow:scroll!important;}

but I end up with this

[image: FullCalendar with large amount of multiple resources]

Add I have no idea how to solve it, would like to know if anyone has an idea or a solution

Thanks